# How to design push notification architecture using channels

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, notifications

I am using push notifications for my application for the first time. I understand that channels can be one of the best way to send push notifications to desired audience.

I have 2 types of notifications, alerts and notices. I want to open corresponding tab according to type of push notifications. AFAIK Push notification is a message rather than an object. How do I put the information of type of notification in the notification so that my client reads it and does corresponding action in callback?

I am using parse.com to send push notification. I am also using ionic framework to create my cordova based app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Google push notifications(GCM).It supports both ios and android even.
[Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

Using GCM  we can send the message tag with the flags we need at clinet side.

```
  {
      "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
      "data" : {
//pass the flag here along with message        
...
      },
    }
```

[more type of message formats can be found here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)